# "The call stack contains only external code" error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Can someone help me out here? Things were running smoothly but suddenly, the debugging stops then it leads me to this -> [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaWU4.png)

What's worse is I tried to do the entire design and code again in a new project thinking that that problem only appears in that one specific project. Wasted about two hours. I'm putting my entire code here in case the problem lies somewhere in my code, this will be long but please help me out. I may have missed something.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    Dim pfc As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
    pfc.AddFontFile("digital-7 (italic).ttf")
    Label2.Font = New Font(pfc.Families(0), 30, FontStyle.Regular)
    Label2.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Dim pfc2 As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
    pfc2.AddFontFile("digital-7.ttf")
    Label1.Font = New Font(pfc2.Families(0), 26, FontStyle.Regular)
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    BtnCase.Hide()
    BtnVer.Hide()
    BtnOff.Hide()
    BtnOn.Hide()
    BtnExp.Hide()
    BtnCube.Hide()
    BtnFact.Hide()
    BtnSqrt.Hide()
    Num7.Hide()
    Num8.Hide()
    Num9.Hide()
    BtnDel.Hide()
    BtnAC.Hide()
    Num4.Hide()
    Num5.Hide()
    Num6.Hide()
    BtnMult.Hide()
    BtnDiv.Hide()
    Num1.Hide()
    Num2.Hide()
    Num3.Hide()
    BtnAdd.Hide()
    BtnSub.Hide()
    Num0.Hide()
    BtnPi.Hide()
    BtnSqrd.Hide()
    BtnDot.Hide()
    BtnEql.Hide()
    BtnUp.Hide()
    BtnDown.Hide()
    BtnLeft.Hide()
    BtnRight.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label2.Text = ""
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCase.Click, BtnVer.Click, BtnOff.Click, BtnOn.Click, BtnExp.Click, BtnCube.Click, BtnFact.Click, BtnSqrt.Click, Num7.Click, Num8.Click, Num9.Click, BtnDel.Click, BtnAC.Click, Num4.Click, Num5.Click, Num6.Click, BtnMult.Click, BtnDiv.Click, Num1.Click, Num2.Click, Num3.Click, BtnAdd.Click, BtnSub.Click, Num0.Click, BtnPi.Click, BtnSqrd.Click, BtnDot.Click, BtnEql.Click, BtnUp.Click, BtnDown.Click, BtnLeft.Click, BtnRight.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    If btn.Name = "BtnCase" Then
        Timer2.Enabled = True
        BtnCase.Hide()
        BtnVer.Hide()
        BtnOff.Hide()
        BtnOn.Hide()
        BtnExp.Hide()
        BtnCube.Hide()
        BtnFact.Hide()
        BtnSqrt.Hide()
        Num7.Hide()
        Num8.Hide()
        Num9.Hide()
        BtnDel.Hide()
        BtnAC.Hide()
        Num4.Hide()
        Num5.Hide()
        Num6.Hide()
        BtnMult.Hide()
        BtnDiv.Hide()
        Num1.Hide()
        Num2.Hide()
        Num3.Hide()
        BtnAdd.Hide()
        BtnSub.Hide()
        Num0.Hide()
        BtnPi.Hide()
        BtnSqrd.Hide()
        BtnDot.Hide()
        BtnEql.Hide()
        BtnUp.Hide()
        BtnDown.Hide()
        BtnLeft.Hide()
        BtnRight.Hide()
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnVer" Then
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = "WE BARE BEARS"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnOff" Then
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = "CASEO"
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        BtnVer.Hide()
        BtnOff.Hide()
        BtnExp.Hide()
        BtnCube.Hide()
        BtnFact.Hide()
        BtnSqrt.Hide()
        Num7.Hide()
        Num8.Hide()
        Num9.Hide()
        BtnDel.Hide()
        BtnAC.Hide()
        Num4.Hide()
        Num5.Hide()
        Num6.Hide()
        BtnMult.Hide()
        BtnDiv.Hide()
        Num1.Hide()
        Num2.Hide()
        Num3.Hide()
        BtnAdd.Hide()
        BtnSub.Hide()
        Num0.Hide()
        BtnPi.Hide()
        BtnSqrd.Hide()
        BtnDot.Hide()
        BtnEql.Hide()
        BtnUp.Hide()
        BtnDown.Hide()
        BtnLeft.Hide()
        BtnRight.Hide()
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnOn" Then
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = 0
        BtnVer.Show()
        BtnOff.Show()
        BtnExp.Show()
        BtnCube.Show()
        BtnFact.Show()
        BtnSqrt.Show()
        Num7.Show()
        Num8.Show()
        Num9.Show()
        BtnDel.Show()
        BtnAC.Show()
        Num4.Show()
        Num5.Show()
        Num6.Show()
        BtnMult.Show()
        BtnDiv.Show()
        Num1.Show()
        Num2.Show()
        Num3.Show()
        BtnAdd.Show()
        BtnSub.Show()
        Num0.Show()
        BtnPi.Show()
        BtnSqrd.Show()
        BtnDot.Show()
        BtnEql.Show()
        BtnUp.Show()
        BtnDown.Show()
        BtnLeft.Show()
        BtnRight.Show()
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnExp" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "^"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnCube" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "^3"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnFact" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "!"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnSqrt" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "√"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num7" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "7"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num8" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "8"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num9" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "9"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnDel" Then
        ' Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "="
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnAC" Then
        ' Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "="
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num4" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "4"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num5" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "5"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num6" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "6"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnMult" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "×"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnDiv" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "÷"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num1" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "1"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num2" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "2"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num3" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "3"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnAdd" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "+"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnSub" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "-"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "Num0" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "0"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnPi" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "π"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnSqrd" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "^2"
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnDot" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "."
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnEql" Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "="
    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnUp" Then

    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnDown" Then

    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnLeft" Then

    End If

    If btn.Name = "BtnRight" Then

    End If

End Sub

Private Const INCREMENT As Integer = 9
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If PictureBox1.Location.Y >= 1050 Then
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        BtnCase.Show()
        BtnOn.Show()
    Else
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y + INCREMENT)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Timer2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    If PictureBox1.Location.Y <= 0 Then
        Timer3.Enabled = False
    Else
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y - INCREMENT)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to step through the code and find the exact location of the exception. You can also put `Try...Catch` in each of your methods and stop inside the Catch

Comment: I'm new with vb.net and programming in general so I'm not really sure how I can do that.

Comment: Learning to debug is a pretty key skill you need to master regardless of if your new with vb.net or any other development language.  Few things to try in addition to the other comments is simply comment out some and see if you program works.  Looking at all the Font handling at the start of your Form_load method for example.  comment them out, and if the program runs add them in one at a time until the error returns.  And it would really be a good idea to go read up on Try/Catch.  Exception handling is another key skill every developer should have a fair handle on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to duplicate code. Two of those long list of `Control.Hide()` are identical, the third only differs by 2 controls (`BtnCase` and `BtnOn`). I have extracted all that to a single method called `HideControls`.

A shorthand for `Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "="` is `Label1.Text &= "=".`

`Select Case` is easier to read and write rather than all those `If` statements.

The actual solution to your error is in the `Font` constructor. The second parameter is expecting a `Single`. When you put the literal 30 and 26 for this parameter, the compiler recognizes this as `Int32` (`Integer`). Ah! The type mismatch (Argument Exception) that the error message mentions. You can correct this by adding an `F` immediately after the number. It will reformat to `30.0` and `26.0` and the compiler will recognize the number as a `Single`.

Numbers are numbers and `Strings` are `Text`. You tried to assign `0` to a `Text` property. This will not compile with Option Strict On which is always should be.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim pfc As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
    pfc.AddFontFile("digital-7 (italic).ttf")
    Label2.Font = New Font(pfc.Families(0), 30.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
    Label2.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Dim pfc2 As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
    pfc2.AddFontFile("digital-7.ttf")
    Label1.Font = New Font(pfc2.Families(0), 26.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    BtnCase.Hide()
    BtnOn.Hide()
    HideControls()
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCase.Click, BtnVer.Click, BtnOff.Click, BtnOn.Click, BtnExp.Click, BtnCube.Click, BtnFact.Click, BtnSqrt.Click, Num7.Click, Num8.Click, Num9.Click, BtnDel.Click, BtnAC.Click, Num4.Click, Num5.Click, Num6.Click, BtnMult.Click, BtnDiv.Click, Num1.Click, Num2.Click, Num3.Click, BtnAdd.Click, BtnSub.Click, Num0.Click, BtnPi.Click, BtnSqrd.Click, BtnDot.Click, BtnEql.Click, BtnUp.Click, BtnDown.Click, BtnLeft.Click, BtnRight.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Select Case btn.Name
        Case "BtnCase"
            Timer2.Enabled = True
            BtnCase.Hide()
            BtnOn.Hide()
            HideControls()
        Case "BtnVer"
            Label1.Text = ""
            Label2.Text = "WE BARE BEARS"
        Case "BtnOff"
            Label1.Text = ""
                Label2.Text = "CASEO"
                Timer1.Enabled = True
                HideControls()
        Case "BtnOn"
            Label1.Text = ""
                Label2.Text = 0
                BtnVer.Show()
                BtnOff.Show()
                BtnExp.Show()
                BtnCube.Show()
                BtnFact.Show()
                BtnSqrt.Show()
                Num7.Show()
                Num8.Show()
                Num9.Show()
                BtnDel.Show()
                BtnAC.Show()
                Num4.Show()
                Num5.Show()
                Num6.Show()
                BtnMult.Show()
                BtnDiv.Show()
                Num1.Show()
                Num2.Show()
                Num3.Show()
                BtnAdd.Show()
                BtnSub.Show()
                Num0.Show()
                BtnPi.Show()
                BtnSqrd.Show()
                BtnDot.Show()
                BtnEql.Show()
                BtnUp.Show()
                BtnDown.Show()
                BtnLeft.Show()
                BtnRight.Show()
        Case "BtnExp"
            Label1.Text &= "^"
        Case "BtnCube"
            Label1.Text &= "^3"
        Case "BtnFact"
            Label1.Text &= "!"
        Case "BtnSqrt"
            Label1.Text &= "√"
        Case "Num7"
            Label1.Text &= "7"
        Case "Num8"
            Label1.Text &= "8"
        Case "Num9"
            Label1.Text &= "9"
        Case "Num4"
            Label1.Text &= "4"
        Case "Num5"
            Label1.Text &= "5"
        Case "Num6"
            Label1.Text &= "6"
        Case "BtnMult"
            Label1.Text &= "×"
        Case "BtnDiv"
            Label1.Text &= "÷"
        Case "Num1"
            Label1.Text &= "1"
        Case "Num2"
            Label1.Text &= "2"
        Case "Num3"
            Label1.Text &= "3"
        Case "BtnAdd"
            Label1.Text &= "+"
        Case "BtnSub"
            Label1.Text &= "-"
        Case "Num0"
            Label1.Text &= "0"
        Case "BtnPi"
            Label1.Text &= "π"
        Case "BtnSqrd"
            Label1.Text &= "^2"
        Case "BtnDot"
            Label1.Text &= "."
        Case "BtnEql"
            Label1.Text &= "="
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub HideControls()
    BtnVer.Hide()
    BtnOff.Hide()
    BtnExp.Hide()
    BtnCube.Hide()
    BtnFact.Hide()
    BtnSqrt.Hide()
    Num7.Hide()
    Num8.Hide()
    Num9.Hide()
    BtnDel.Hide()
    BtnAC.Hide()
    Num4.Hide()
    Num5.Hide()
    Num6.Hide()
    BtnMult.Hide()
    BtnDiv.Hide()
    Num1.Hide()
    Num2.Hide()
    Num3.Hide()
    BtnAdd.Hide()
    BtnSub.Hide()
    Num0.Hide()
    BtnPi.Hide()
    BtnSqrd.Hide()
    BtnDot.Hide()
    BtnEql.Hide()
    BtnUp.Hide()
    BtnDown.Hide()
    BtnLeft.Hide()
    BtnRight.Hide()
End Sub
```

You could save a lot of code if you set the `Tag` property at design time of each button handled by to the appropriate string. Set the buttons with `""` to `String.Empty`. We need the `.ToString` because the `Tag` property is an `Object`.

The `ShowControls` method doesn't save any typing but in makes the button click code much cleaner.

```
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCase.Click, BtnVer.Click, BtnOff.Click, BtnOn.Click, BtnExp.Click, BtnCube.Click, BtnFact.Click, BtnSqrt.Click, Num7.Click, Num8.Click, Num9.Click, BtnDel.Click, BtnAC.Click, Num4.Click, Num5.Click, Num6.Click, BtnMult.Click, BtnDiv.Click, Num1.Click, Num2.Click, Num3.Click, BtnAdd.Click, BtnSub.Click, Num0.Click, BtnPi.Click, BtnSqrd.Click, BtnDot.Click, BtnEql.Click, BtnUp.Click, BtnDown.Click, BtnLeft.Click, BtnRight.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Label1.Text = btn.Tag.ToString
    Select Case btn.Name
        Case "BtnCase"
            Timer2.Enabled = True
            BtnCase.Hide()
            BtnOn.Hide()
            HideControls()
        Case "BtnVer"
            Label2.Text = "WE BARE BEARS"
        Case "BtnOff"
            Label2.Text = "CASEO"
            Timer1.Enabled = True
            HideControls()
        Case "BtnOn"
            Label2.Text = "0"
            ShowControls()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub ShowControls()
    BtnVer.Show()
    BtnOff.Show()
    BtnExp.Show()
    BtnCube.Show()
    BtnFact.Show()
    BtnSqrt.Show()
    Num7.Show()
    Num8.Show()
    Num9.Show()
    BtnDel.Show()
    BtnAC.Show()
    Num4.Show()
    Num5.Show()
    Num6.Show()
    BtnMult.Show()
    BtnDiv.Show()
    Num1.Show()
    Num2.Show()
    Num3.Show()
    BtnAdd.Show()
    BtnSub.Show()
    Num0.Show()
    BtnPi.Show()
    BtnSqrd.Show()
    BtnDot.Show()
    BtnEql.Show()
    BtnUp.Show()
    BtnDown.Show()
    BtnLeft.Show()
    BtnRight.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: I just saw this, thank you very much! I have been trying to find a way to shorten my code, you helped me a great deal. Thank you, really!